# Google model-viewer - How to fully rotate around the model?

Tags: model-viewer

When using Google's model-viewer, it's not possible to see the model from above, the orbit of the camera seems limited to some arbitrary angle.
I've tried to set `max-camera-orbit` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a link? the current limit seems to be close to the normal of the polar north of the model. Do you want to be able to go beyond that (i.e. make the model upside down)?